# Looping through a table column of data to build a string

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to loop through a table column and build up a string.

This is what I have so far:

```
$(".ConvertSQL").click(function () {

        var values

        $(".TableQuery tr").each(function () {

            $('td', this).each(function () {
                values = value + ',' + value;

                alert(values)
            })

        })

    });
```

**Error Received:**

My alert shows a message saying **'undefined'** and keeps repeating this for the number of times there is data in cells

I'm still new to this, so don't fully understand whats happening.

The setup at the moment wont loop through a column, I think its going through every cell in the table so ill need to change that as well

Comment: What are you expecting `value` to be?  It's not defined anywhere in your code.  Are you looking for `$(this).text()` instead?  To get the text of the `td` element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in your logic is because although you define `value` you never actually set it to hold the value of anything, hence it remains `undefined`.

From the context of your code it looks like you're trying to get the text content from the `td` elements, as such you can use the `text()` method along with `:nth-child()` to get the `td` of the required column.

Also note that to make this even easier you can use `map()` to build an array of the values which you then `join()` to form the single string. Try this:

```js
$(".ConvertSQL").click(function() {
  var str = $(".TableQuery td:nth-child(1)").map((i, e) => $(e).text()).get().join(' ');
  console.log(str);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="TableQuery">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Foo</td>
      <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Fizz</td>
      <td>Buzz</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button class="ConvertSQL">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Morning Rory, appreciate this thank you - I am struggling to use it though. I've ran your snippet and it works fine, but when I implement it to my project I get the following message: adHocQueryBuilder.js, Line: 4, Column: 64. Line 64 holds the following: var str = $(".TableQuery td:nth-child(1)").map((i, e) => $(e).text()).get().join(' ');

Comment: you were spot on, I just tried it in Chrome and it worked. tried your anonymous function in IE but still cant get that working. I guess using Chrome will do for now. Much appreciated

Comment: Sorry, I got it wrong in the previous example (which is why I hate typing code in comments :) This should work properly: `var str = $(".TableQuery td:nth-child(1)").map(function(i, e) { return $(e).text(); }).get().join(' ');`

Comment: Just tried it - Worked a treat. Thanks for you time, this is great